# Help me identifiy this moth?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy, lepidoptera

I found this moth in **Bengaluru/India**. Its body length was nearly 2cm. Brown colored with three yellow rings.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a handmaiden moth (***Syntomoides imaon***) which has been observed in this part of India.

[image]

Source: [India Biodiversity Portal](https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/268845)